# How can I attach an arm to a double-flat drive stepper motor?

Tags: motor, design, mechanism, joint, rotation

This is my first robotics experience, outside of one class 10 years ago. I've been Googling this question for about an hour but I can't find an answer!

I'm using a ROHS Step Motor 28BYJ-48 (with an Arduino Uno). The rotating shaft that sticks out of the step motor seems to be called a "double-flat drive". It's less than 1/4" wide, and is flattened on two sides.

[image: stepper motor]

I need to attach a 6" long arm to it, so the arm can spin like the second hand on a wall clock, but in both directions. **What can I use to attach the arm securely to the shaft?** What's the name of the part that will couple this double-flat drive shaft to a straight, flat piece at a right angle to it? Or are there flat metal circles with holes in them that can be coupled to the double-flat drive shaft without slipping - and what's the Google search phrase I should use to find them?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a D or Double D shaped shaft collar/coupler.  Or obtain a Double D shaped punch, depending on the design of the piece you are attaching to the shaft.

Comment: Thanks SteveO. The collar/coupler seems simplest to me, since the arm I'm attaching is a 1/2" square wooden dowel. However, the collars I've found online (Ruland, Amazon) seem to just create a cylindrical hole when attached to the shaft. How does the arm then get attached at a right angle to the collar/coupler? Or am I looking at the wrong kinds of collars/couplers?

Comment: A ser screw could work, but you have to make sure it doesn’t back out.  You can find D shaped couplers, such as this:  https://www.robotshop.com/en/0770-set-screw-d-hub-6mm-bore.html

Comment: Looks like a "mounting hub" is what I might need! Thanks for the guidance.