# How to attach plate to stepper motor?

Tags: arduino, motor, servomotor, stepper-motor

Total noob here (never touched Arduino before today), & have pretty much no hands-on technical experience (although with lack of experience, I make up in enthusiasm to learn!)

**Question:** How do you attach a plate (material of plate yet to be decided, likely stiff cardboard) to a stepper motor? See image demonstration below:

[image: Screenshot]

Do I punch a hole in the middle of my plate and super glue the hole to the motor shaft?

The end goal is to have a rotating plate like a microwave (the plate will hold some items).

**Summary;** How do you securely attach a plate to a stepper motor without it collapsing from the weight of the plate? Should I even be putting a plate onto a stepper motor? Or should I use a servomotor?

Thank you!

Comment: Noting cross post from https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/85307/how-to-attach-plate-to-stepper-motor The advice Majenko gave about rollers to support the weight was good. The stepper and coupling can bear very little weight.

Answer (score 2):

Have a Google at double flat drive couplers, sometimes called oval, or dual drive flat.

Something like this might do the trick:
[image]

Also see [How can I attach an arm to a double-flat drive stepper motor?](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/18277/how-can-i-attach-an-arm-to-a-double-flat-drive-stepper-motor/18280#18280)

Comment: @Tee those are typically just a few dollars on aliexpress.com. Leave a commnet if can't find them.